# Rotating the player model to point towards a point

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, coordinate-transformation

I have seen the post from three years ago asking a somewhat similar question about how to achieve this with `glm::lookAt`, but couldn't quite apply it to my game.

I have a camera and player model moving on a curve. This is done by calculating points on the curve and simply moving the player there with `glm::translate (identityMatrix, positionCameraIsCurrentlyAt)`, hence I have a current position on the curve and also a `nextPosition`.
I now want to rotate the model, using a transformation matrix, but can't seem to get it done. My first idea was to calculate a vector that is `currentPosition - nextPosition` to get a vector I should be facing to, I called that `targetPoint`. And calculating the vector I am currently facing by simply setting it to (0, 0, 1) for the startup (as you look towards negative z, I guess that's how models are oriented) and updating it to the `targetPoint` vector after rotating.
Bot of the vectors are normalized btw.

The code looked like this:

```cpp
glm::vec3 targetPoint = glm::normalize(position - curveIter->calcCurvePosition(curveProgress));
glm::mat4 rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, glm::radians(glm::angle(pointingTowards, targetPoint)), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
glm::mat4 translationMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, position);

// Test print vectors and angle 
std::cout << targetPoint.x << ", " << targetPoint.y << ", " << targetPoint.z << ", " << "pointing towards: " << pointingTowards.x << ", " <<pointingTowards.y << ", " << pointingTowards.z << ", " << glm::angle(glm::normalize(pointingTowards), forward) << std::endl;
pointingTowards = targetPoint;

// Test print vectors and angle 
std::cout << targetPoint.x << ", " << targetPoint.y << ", " << targetPoint.z << ", " << "pointing towards: " << pointingTowards.x << ", " << pointingTowards.y << ", " << pointingTowards.z << ", " << glm::angle(glm::normalize(pointingTowards), forward) << std::endl;

return translationMatrix*rotationMatrix;
```

This didn't really rotate the model at all. I printed the vectors and angle to check them and the results where this:

`targetPoint`: (-0.97509, 0, 0.22181)

`pointingTowards`: (-0.97509, 0, 0.22181)

`angle`: 3.14159

So it seems like they are all way too small. This, I imagine, could be due to the normalization... However, the method says both vectors need to be normalized. The `angle` is always Pi which might seem odd but is due to the curve being a circle. This is, obviously, not true for the first `angle` which is 2.35469 due to the vectors being `targetPoint`(-0.708167, 0, 0.706045) and `pointingTowards`: (0, 0, 1) respectively.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?
Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have a `position` and a `targetPoint`, then you've just to define an up-vector (e.g. `glm::vec3 upVector(0, 1, 0)` and you can use `glm::lookAt(position, targetPoint, upVector)` to define a view matrix. Anyway it is unclear what you try to achieve. Do you want to compute a view matrix? Is the point of view `position`? Or do you wnat to compute a model transformation?

Comment: Oh, yeah, should clarify that!

I want to build the model matrix of my player object that I can then load into my model loading. So I need a rotation transformation matrix, I guess. the translate part works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `position` and a `targetPoint`. You can define an `upVec` and compute the axis of the rotation matrix by the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) as follows:

```cpp
glm::vec3 upVec(0, 1, 0);

glm::vec3 z_axis = glm::normalize(targetPoint - position);
glm::vec3 x_axis = glm::normalize(glm::cross(upVec, z_axis));
glm::vec3 y_axis = glm::normalize(glm::cross(z_axis, x_axis));

glm::mat4 rotationMatrix(
    glm::vec4(x_axis, 0),
    glm::vec4(y_axis, 0),
    glm::vec4(z_axis, 0),
    glm::vec4(0, 0, 0, 1));
```

---

Another possibility is to use a [Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).

```cpp
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>
```

Define a rotation from (0, 0, 1) to `tragetVec` and convert the quaternion to a rotation matrix:

```cpp
glm::vec3 tragetVec = glm::normalize(targetPoint - position);
glm::quat rotQuat = glm::rotation(glm::vec3(0, 0, 1), tragetVec);
rotationMatrix = glm::toMat4(rotQuat);
```

Comment: What would I need the axis for?
Isn't that supposedly already what glm::rotate does?

Comment: oook, I have no idea why it works with your code and not with glm::rotate, but I very much appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: @KonstiLackner You rotation matrix just rotates around the y axis `glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)` (left and right), but not up and down (around the x axis `glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)`)

Comment: That's why I gave glm::rotate the y axis as rotation axis